# displaybreaks and braket package

Tags: line-breaking, displaystyle, braket, displaybreak

I'm trying to allow a long formula consisting of a large set definition to break among more lines. I want to define the set using the `braket` package that is very handy to typeset sets. Specifically I'm using the `\Braket{...}` command, not the default `\Set` command (but I don't think it makes any difference), e.g.

```
\[ S \coloneqq \Braket{ x \in \N | ... very long conditions here ...} \]
```

However, setting `\allowdisplaybreaks` in the preamble does not work on its own.
Also, trying to manually force linebreak with `\\` inside an `align` environment does not work either (probably because of how ´\braket´ works internally, but I'm not sure since I'm not an expert).

Any suggestion?

P.S.: I know that some variants of this question have been (largely) discussed before, but I've found nothing regarding the `braket` package specifically. However, if you have any other recommendation to **easily** typeset sets it is welcomed!

**UPDATE**: not sure why this question have been put on hold, anyway I'll add a concrete example to clarify my question. Here is the raw version of what I want to achieve (it's the presentation of a group, if you know a bit of algebra)

```
\[ S = \Braket{ a,\ b,\ c,\ d \ | \ abcd = dcba,\ a^2 = d^2,\ a^{cd} = b^{cb},\ abc = bca,\ dbd = aca,\ \text{ ... possibly other conditions... } } \]
```

And here is the best solution I've found so far

```
\[ S = \Braket{ a,\ b,\ c,\ d \ | \ 
    \begin{aligned}
         abcd &= dcba, & a^2 &= d^2, & a^{cd}  &= b^{cb},\\
         adda &= dbba, & c^2 &= b^2, & a^{d^3} &= b^{a^2},\\
         abc  &= bca,  & dbd &= aca, & b^{a^2} &= c^2
    \end{aligned}\ }
\]
```

The only downside so far is that the left and right brackets and the middle `|` do not stretch enough when the condition contains 3 or more lines.

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) `\displaybreaks` is only relevant to muliline constructions, `\[... \]` is single line. (3) It will be a lot easier to help you if you provide a full minimal example, others can just copy and test without having to add anything. (4) No idea how `\Braket` is defined, but it may be made in such a way that align cannot see any ``\\`` inside it, and thus have no effect. This is one of the reasone why my recommended `\Set` construction (see `mathtools` manual) contain a separate definition for the `|` notation, such that this symbol can be used separately in special cases.

Comment: The `\Braket` constructions and friends do not allow line breaks.  Incidentally, the package provides a `\Set` construction too, but with the same draw back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a `set` command with `mathtools`. In the documentation, a code by Sébastien Gouezel allows for line breaks:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand\MTkillspecial[1]{% helper macro
\bgroup
\catcode`\&=9
\let\\\relax%
\scantokens{#1}%
\egroup
}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\set\{\}

\begin{document}

\[
 S\coloneqq\begin{multlined}[t]
 \set[\Big]{
 x\in\mathbf N \:\Bigm | \: \text{a first quite long condition} \\[-1ex] \text{and another still much longer condition}}
 \end{multlined}
\]

\[
 S\coloneqq\begin{aligned}[t]
 \set[\Big]{
 x\in\mathbf N \:\Bigm | \: & \text{a first quite long condition} \\[-1ex] & \text{and another still much longer condition}}
 \end{aligned}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, however this solution is pretty long and complex to write every time I need a set definition on multiple lines. Moreover, I like my LaTex document to be as clean as possible so that you can clearly read them even from the source.

Comment: @Sirion: What's clearer than writing a `\set` command? You also can write an `aligned` environment inside `\set`,. This requires no `\MTkillspecial`, but you'll get  really huge braces. I'll add an example of how it looks in a moment.

Comment: Ok, maybe I'm being a bit too demanding, it's just that I was hoping for an even more concise solution (without using a nested environment). Anyway, if nothing better comes along in some days I'll accept your answer. Thank you, again.