# How to define a bracket function that allows line breaking and auto-adjusts size?

Tags: line-breaking, brackets, mathtools

I want to define a bracket function that **allows line breaking** and **auto-adjusts the size** of the bracket like the normal method did. By normal method I mean using `\left\{\right\}`.

According to [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/435515/displaybreaks-and-braket-package), a `set` function can be defined to allow line breaking, but one needs to add the size option `\set[\big]` to manually specify the size. This is not exactly what I want.

Now according to the original [mathtools documentation](https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/mathtools/mathtools.pdf), the `\abs` function apparently works very well. So I did the exact same thing:

```
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand\MTkillspecial[1]{% helper macro
  \bgroup
  \catcode‘\&=9
  \let\\\relax%
  \scantokens{#1}%
  \egroup
  }
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\Bqty\{\}
\reDeclarePairedDelimiterInnerWrapper\Bqty{star}{
  \mathopen{#1\vphantom{\MTkillspecial{#2}}\kern-\nulldelimiterspace\right.}
  #2
  \mathclose{\left.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace\vphantom{\MTkillspecial{#2}}#3}
  }
```

And I use the following example to test it:

```
\begin{align*}
  A=\Bqty*{\frac{B}{E}+\frac{C}{E}\\+\frac{D}{E}}
\end{align*}
```

But what I got is `Missing number, treated as zero` error. 
An [overleaf project](https://www.overleaf.com/3618489414tfkcqvqswwxd) is created for convenient testing if anyone ever needs a MWE.

How should I properly define this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in line 4 of your code: you needed a `grave accent`, not a quote:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{mathtools}

    \newcommand\MTkillspecial[1]{% helper macro
    \bgroup
    \catcode`\&=9 %% problem was here
    \let\\\relax%
    \scantokens{#1}%
    \egroup
    }

\DeclarePairedDelimiter\Bqty\{\}%% ou \brkbraces
\reDeclarePairedDelimiterInnerWrapper\Bqty{star}{
  \mathopen{#1\vphantom{\MTkillspecial{#2}}\kern-\nulldelimiterspace\right.}
  #2
  \mathclose{\left.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace\vphantom{\MTkillspecial{#2}}#3}
  }%}

    \begin{document}

And I use the following example to test it:

\begin{align*}
 A & =
\begin{aligned}[t]\Bqty*{\frac{B}{E} & +\frac{C}{E}\\ & +\frac{D}{E}}
 \end{aligned}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]